# Subclassing Objective C Class methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, inheritance

I have a question regarding Subclassing and Class methods.

I have a base class `MyBaseClass` which has a convenience class method

`+ (id)giveMeAClassUsing:(NSString *)someParameter;`

`MyBaseClass` is not a singleton.

Now, I wish to create a subclass of `MyBaseClass`, let's call it `MyChildClass`. I wish to have the same class method on `MyChildClass` as well. Additionally, I also wish to initialize an instance variable on `MyChildClass` when I do that.

Would doing something like this:

```
+ (id)giveMeAClassUsing:(NSString *)someParameter {

      MyChildClass *anInstance = [super giveMeAClassUsing:someParameter];
      anInstance.instanceVariable = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];

      return anInstance;
}
```

be valid?

Thanks for all your help (in advance) and for resolving my confusion and clarifying some concepts!

Cheers!

Comment: Yup; this is the key difference between true *class methods* and *static methods*....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That will work fine.

Possibly better would be to define your convenience constructor in such a way that you don't *need* to override it:

```
 + (id)myClassWithString: (NSString *)string {
     return [[[self alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease];
 }
```

This will do the right thing no matter which of your superclass or any of its subclasses it is called in.

Then change just the `initWithString:` method in your *subclass* to handle the initialization:

```
- (id)initWithString: (NSString *)string {
    return [self initWithString:string andImageView:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame] autorelease]] ;
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to elucidate on that a little more please? My current base class implementation is : `+ (id)giveMeAClassUsing:(NSString *)someParameter { BaseClass *anInstance = [[self alloc] initUsingCustomInstanceMethod:aParameter]; return anInstance;}` So, do I only need to override `initUsingCustomInstanceMethod:aParameter` in my child class?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, yes. The way you have it will work fine, too, but were I reading your code, I'd probably expect just the `init...` method to be overridden.

Comment: Awesome sauce. You are right!!! It totally skipped my mind that I'll be referring to `[ChildClass giveMeAClassUsing:aParameter]`, owing to which the baseClass's code, which calls `[self alloc]`, would actually be referring to the ChildClass. Then, I call a `[super initUsingCustomInstanceMethod:aParameter]` and do my custom initialization. :D Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just as a confirmation, from the way I'm seeing it, I'll still need to call `[super initUsingCustomInstanceMethod:aParameter]` from my child class's custom initializer, correct?

Comment: You need to call the superclass's designated intializer from the subclass's designated initializer. For my suggestion, that would mean doing `[super initUsingCustomInstanceMethod:aParameter]` inside the subclass's `initUsingCustomInstanceMethod:andImageView:`.

Comment: Yep yep. :) Exactly what I was asking! Thanks again Mr. Cousteau! :)

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely that's valid.

One note though is in the superclass, reference the class itself with `self`, rather than the superclass by name.

This is bad:

```
// MySuperClass // BAD :(
+ (id)giveMeAClassUsing:(NSString *)someParameter {
  return [[[MySuperClass alloc] initWithParam:someParameter] autorelease];
}
```

But this is good!

```
// MySuperClass // GOOD! :D
+ (id)giveMeAClassUsing:(NSString *)someParameter {
  return [[[self alloc] initWithParam:someParameter] autorelease];
}
```

Otherwise when you subclass, and then call super you aren't actually initializing the right class.  Use of `self` allows the class being instantiated to vary without overriding the class method.

Comment: Yep yep. As posted in the comment above, that's how I initialize my superClass: `+ (id)giveMeAClassUsing:(NSString *)someParameter { BaseClass *anInstance = [[self alloc] initUsingCustomInstanceMethod:aParameter]; return anInstance;}`

Comment: Thank you, for the prompt response and suggestion though. :)